# Video Uploading: recommended process?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Hey just a quick question for anyone who has done this. I want to create a video tube site. I have done file uploads before but was wondering if anyone could give me suggestions on what I am planning to do.

**The way I am planning** is to have a folder in my web directory and to upload videos into the folder after virus scanning and checking mime. The video will then be converted and compressed using FFMPEG into flv.

I will change the name and store the video reference id in mysql so the file name can be fetched and served.

I will serve the files using HTTP_Download to a flash player

```
$dl = new HTTP_Download();
$dl->setFile("$path");
$dl->setContentDisposition(HTTP_DOWNLOAD_ATTACHMENT, "$path");
$dl->setContentType('video/flv');
$dl->send();
```

**Anyone have any suggestions? Is it a good idea to put all videos in one directory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider a Java based uploader as PHP can run into timeout problems on large uploads.

Also do you FFMPEG processing as a CRON job not at upload as it takes a long time.

Look in something like [Wowza Streaming Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) to serve the videos. Allows streaming and everything is above the root. I name each video with a UID and send a parameter to the Flash video player to decide which one to play.

Comment: Thanks niggles, what do you mean by a cron job?

Comment: And also, what exactly is Wowza, a place to store videos and stream like a separate server provider?

Comment: A CRON job is an automated process that you can set to run at a certain interval. So rather than process the video straight away, put it in a temp directory and write a database entry with an "unprocessed" flag. The cron job would look every minute for "unprocessed" entries and process them in the background. Wowza is a streaming media server (software) you install on your own server.

Comment: Because when a movie is served via a normal connection it has to load each frame consecutively i.e you can't skip ahead without loading the previous data (like with an old VHS video). With a proper streaming media server you can skip to anywhere without it needing to be loaded (like a DVD). This cuts down on bandwidth + protects your video stream + provides robust stats.

Answer (score 1):

Where and how you store them will largely depend on how secure they need to be (i.e. should people be able to access the files in the directory directly? or should it be stored more securely than that?)

If direct access is fine, then putting them all in one folder is okay. If not, then you may want to obscure folder names, store them in a secure Database, or in a folder that is not accessible outside of the server.

Also, I'm hoping you're aware of the massive amounts of storage space and bandwidth such a service will consume? I hope you have a scaled solution ready to deploy if you're really serious about this..

Comment: I am aware of the bandwidth and usage. I am building a solution but I will have to scale it as I go. I have limited funds haha. Any recommended server providers? Should I just start with a dedicated server? Also, I don't want the users to access the videos unless they are streaming them, so you are saying I should make a folder for each video upload?

Comment: Definitely not a new folder for each upload. I'd opt for storing them out of your main web directory where direct access isn't possible from outside the server. Then just stream them to an accessible place from there.

Comment: How do you access a file that is outside of your root web directory? You mentioned stream them to a place. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Well on your server, you will have a root web directory such as 'public_html' or 'www'. Any unsecured folders within this root directory are accessible via HTTP. Placing any files *outside* this root directory will make them *inaccessible* via HTTP, but still accessible to server resources such as PHP scripts. Thus, you could set up some sort of streaming player (or use the streaming server mentioned by niggles) which would then grab them from that directory.